# Selecting all inputs with same name returns 1 value

Tags: jquery, forms

i have a form with 16 numerical inputs, i have written a "click" function as follows :

```
$("#continue").click(function (e) {
      var mealOption = $("input[name='option[]']").val();
      console.log(mealOption);
}
```

This is only returning 1 value although ALL 16 inputs are using the same name : option[], regardless of how many number inputs I enter, it will only return 1 value which is the first value in the list of inputs.

Where have i gone wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you paste your html as well please?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/val/) on the `.val()` method:

> Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched
>   elements or set the value of every matched element.

Which means that when your DOM search query returns a collection, only the 1st element would be selected for processing.

But, if you have all your `<input>` elements in a `<form>`, you can use `.serialize()` or `.serializeArray()`:

```js
$('form').on('submit', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  const v = $(this).serializeArray();
  $('.values').text(JSON.stringify(v, null, '  '));
});
```

```css
.values {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="option" placeholder="input 1" />
    <input type="text" name="option" placeholder="input 2" />
    <input type="text" name="option" placeholder="input 3" />
    <button type="submit">get values</button>
  </form>
  <pre class="values">input values...</pre>
</body>
```

Otherwise, you do something like this:

```
$('input[name="option"]').each(function () { console.log($(this).val()); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over each of the 16 items.

```
$("input[name='option[]']").each(function(opt) {
  var mealOption = opt.val();
  console.log(mealOption);
});
```

`$("input[name='option[]']")` is getting all 16 items, but when you call `.val()` jQuery picked the first items (under the covers).